# parameter of s:link action is null

Tags: jsf

I have a link in every row of a datatable. On click, it is supposed to execute the test(_item) method in the controller, but the _item is always null.

Here is the code:

```
<rich:datatable value="#{controller.items}" var="_item">
    <rich:column>
        <s:link view="/nextPage.xhtml" propagation="nested" action="controler.test(_item)">
            <h:outputText value="click!" />
        </s:link>
    </rich:column>
</rich:datatable>
```

Anyone knows a fix?

Comment: What tag library is the `s:` prefix referring to?

Comment: Are you using JSF 1.2 or 2, Richfaces 3 or 4, Seam 2 or 3?